# Jcombobox not displayed correctly

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlabel, jcombobox

I'm trying to put a JComboBox on a Jpanel, if i clicked shows the contents of the combobox, but it was not showed. the content appears only if I move the cursor on top of it. the Jpanel contains a Jlabel with a picture and on top of it a Jcombobox.

[image: Jcombobox]

PanelRegionlACTEL:

```
package com.springJPA.vue.appACTEL;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import com.jd.swing.custom.component.button.StandardButton;
import com.jd.swing.custom.component.jcombobox.MyComboBoxEditor;
import com.jd.swing.custom.component.jcombobox.MyComboBoxRenderer;
import com.jd.swing.util.Theme;
import com.springJPA.domain.Numero;
import com.springJPA.domain.Region;
import com.springJPA.domain.Resedence;
import com.springJPA.service.ActelsService;
import com.springJPA.service.FonctionDAO;
import com.springJPA.service.NumeroService;
import com.springJPA.service.RegionService;
import com.springJPA.service.ResedenceService;
import com.springJPA.service.VilleService;
import com.springJPA.vue.App;

public class PanelRegionlACTEL extends JPanel {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3805099295102746248L;

    public static JComboBox<String> comboBox_gouver;
    public static JComboBox<String> comboBox_ACTELS;
    public static JComboBox<String> comboBoxVille;

    private JButton okButton;
    private JButton cancelButton;

    private JProgressBar progressBar;
    int value = 0;
    int nbp = 0;

    public   int selectedIndexR;
    public   int selectedIndexA;
    public   int selectedIndexV;

    public JLabel labelR1;   
    public boolean tr=false;
    FonctionDAO fonctionDAO = new FonctionDAO();

    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("application-context.xml");
    RegionService rgService = (RegionService) context.getBean("regionService");
    ActelsService atlService = (ActelsService) context.getBean("actelService");
    VilleService villeService = (VilleService) context.getBean("villeService");
    NumeroService numeroService = (NumeroService) context.getBean("numeroService");
    ResedenceService resedenceService = (ResedenceService) context.getBean("resedenceService");

    /*public static void main(String[] args)

       {

    try {
          UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {

            System.out.println("Erreur LookAndFeel"+e);
        }

    try{

       new PanelAccueilACTEL(); 

       }catch (Exception e)  { 
           System.out.println("Erreur App: "+e);
           e.printStackTrace();  
           }

       }*/

    /**
     * Create the panel.
     */
    public PanelRegionlACTEL() {

        setLayout(null);
        setBorder(null);
        setOpaque(false);
        setBounds(0, 0, 803, 534);
        setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
        setSize(803, 534);
        setVisible(true);

        JButton buttonQuitter = new JButton("");
        buttonQuitter.setIcon(new ImageIcon(PanelRegionlACTEL.class.getResource("/ap/s/tn/img/btn.PNG")));
        buttonQuitter.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        buttonQuitter.setIcon(new ImageIcon(PanelLoginACTEL.class.getResource("/ap/s/tn/img/btn.PNG")));
        buttonQuitter.setOpaque(true);
        buttonQuitter.setSelectedIcon(new ImageIcon(App.class.getResource("/ap/s/tn/img/btn2.PNG")));
        buttonQuitter.setFocusPainted(false);
        buttonQuitter.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        buttonQuitter.setBorderPainted(false);
        buttonQuitter.setBounds(618, 420, 144, 41);
        add(buttonQuitter);

        JMenuReseau();
        JMenuItemRegion();
        JMenuDemandes();

        JRadioButtonMenuItemNinstallation();
        JRadioButtonMenuItemTransfaire();



        JLabel lblLoginApplicationFta = new JLabel("Region application ACTEL");
        lblLoginApplicationFta.setFont(new Font("Segoe Print", Font.BOLD, 16));
        lblLoginApplicationFta.setForeground(new Color(255, 0, 0));
        lblLoginApplicationFta.setBounds(6, 6, 229, 28);
        add(lblLoginApplicationFta);

        JLabel lblslectionnerUnGouvernorat = new JLabel("<html><font color='#09024D'>S\u00E9lectionner un gouvernorat</font></html>");
        lblslectionnerUnGouvernorat.setFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.PLAIN, 18));
        lblslectionnerUnGouvernorat.setBounds(54, 107, 242, 25);
        add(lblslectionnerUnGouvernorat);

        comboBox_gouver = new JComboBox<String>();
        comboBox_gouver.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<String>(new String[] {"---------------------"}));
        afficherLISTE_REGION();
        comboBox_gouver.setBounds(323, 106, 118, 26);
        comboBox_gouver.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                  selectedIndexR = comboBox_gouver.getSelectedIndex();
                  selectedIndexA = comboBox_ACTELS.getSelectedIndex();

                if(selectedIndexR == 0) {
                    comboBox_ACTELS.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<String> (new String[] {"---------------------"}));
                    comboBoxVille.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<String>(new String[] {"---------------------"}));
                    }
                else{  
                      afficherLISTE_ACTEL_PAR_REGION();
                     }
            }
        });
        add(comboBox_gouver);

        comboBox_ACTELS = new JComboBox<String>();
        //comboBox_ACTELS.setRenderer(new MyComboBoxRenderer());
        //comboBox_ACTELS.setEditor(new MyComboBoxEditor());
        comboBox_ACTELS.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<String>(new String[] {"---------------------"}));
        comboBox_ACTELS.setBounds(323, 134, 118, 26);
        comboBox_ACTELS.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e2) {
        int indexA = comboBox_ACTELS.getSelectedIndex(); 
            if(indexA == 0){
                comboBoxVille.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<String>(new String[] {"---------------------"}));
            }
            else{   
                     afficherLISTE_VILLE_PAR_ACTEL();
                }   
            }
        });

        JLabel lblchoixActels = new JLabel("<html><font color='#09024D'>Choix ACTELS</font></html>");
        lblchoixActels.setFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.PLAIN, 18));
        lblchoixActels.setBounds(54, 139, 133, 16);
        add(lblchoixActels);
        add(comboBox_ACTELS);

        JLabel lblville = new JLabel("<html><font color='#09024D'>Ville</font></html>");
        lblville.setFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.PLAIN, 18));
        lblville.setBounds(54, 170, 42, 16);
        add(lblville);

        comboBoxVille = new JComboBox<String>();
        comboBoxVille.setBounds(323, 165, 118, 26);
        comboBoxVille.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<String>(new String[] {"---------------------"}));
        add(comboBoxVille);

        progressBar = new JProgressBar();
        progressBar.setBounds(54, 198, 154, 19);
        progressBar.setVisible(false);
        add(progressBar);

        StandardButton button = new StandardButton("OK", Theme.GLOSSY_BLUE_THEME);
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                 App.cl_conteneurPaneau.show(App.conteneurPaneau, "panelAccueilACTEL");

                 int indexRegion = comboBox_gouver.getSelectedIndex();
                 int indexActel = comboBox_ACTELS.getSelectedIndex();
                 int indexVille = comboBoxVille.getSelectedIndex();

                 String region = comboBox_gouver.getSelectedItem().toString();
                 String ville = comboBoxVille.getSelectedItem().toString();

                        if((indexRegion==0)&&(indexActel==0)&&(indexVille==0)){
                            labelR1.setText("selectioner tout champs");
                        }
                        else if((indexActel==0)&&(indexVille==0)){
                            labelR1.setText("selectioner tout champs");
                        }

                        else{    
                                  action();  
                                  labelR1.setForeground(new Color(0, 128, 0));
                                  labelR1.setText("region :  "+region);
                                  region = comboBox_gouver.getSelectedItem().toString();
                                  ville = comboBoxVille.getSelectedItem().toString();

                                  PanelAccueilACTEL.getLabelR().setText("<html><body><b>Region: "+region+"</b></body></html>");
                                  PanelAccueilACTEL.getLabelV().setText("<html><body><b>*Ville: "+ville+"</b></body></html>");

                                  remplir_code_postal();
                                  remplir_numero();
                                  remplir_type_voie();
                             }
            }
            });
        button.setActionCommand("OK");
        button.setBounds(54, 250, 80, 28);
        add(button);

        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/tn/pack/image/cadre-rg.png"));
        Image zoom = scaleImage(icon.getImage(), 934);
        Icon iconScaled = new ImageIcon(zoom);

        labelR1 = new JLabel("");
        labelR1.setBounds(250, 258, 133, 14);
        add(labelR1);

        JLabel cadre = new JLabel(iconScaled);
        cadre.setIcon(new ImageIcon(PanelLoginACTEL.class.getResource("/tn/pack/image/cadre-rg.png")));
        cadre.setBounds(6, 70, 486, 305);
        add(cadre);

        JLabel arrirePlan = new JLabel("");
        arrirePlan.setIcon(new ImageIcon(PanelRegionlACTEL.class.getResource("/ap/s/tn/img/bot.png")));
        arrirePlan.setBounds(0, 0, 803, 534);
        add(arrirePlan);

    }

    public void remplir_type_voie() {
        List<Resedence> listeTypeVoie = fonctionDAO.afficherLISTE_TYPE_VOIE(resedenceService);
        for(Resedence resedence:listeTypeVoie) {
            PanelNouvelleInstallation.comboBox_typeVoie.addItem(resedence.getType_voie());
            PanelDemandeTransfertACTEL.comboBox_typeVoieA.addItem(resedence.getType_voie());
            PanelDemandeTransfertACTEL.comboBox_typeVoieN.addItem(resedence.getType_voie());
          }
    }

    public void remplir_code_postal() {
        PanelNouvelleInstallation.textField_codepostal.setText(getcodePostal()+"");
        PanelDemandeTransfertACTEL.textField_codepostalA.setText(getcodePostal()+"");
        PanelDemandeTransfertACTEL.textField_codepostalN.setText(getcodePostal()+"");
    }

    protected void afficherLISTE_VILLE_PAR_ACTEL() {
        try {
                comboBoxVille.removeAllItems();
                String nom_actel = comboBox_ACTELS.getSelectedItem().toString();
                int id_actel = fonctionDAO.afficherID_ACTEL_PAR_NOM_ACTEL(atlService, nom_actel);
                List<String> listeVille= fonctionDAO.afficherLISTE_VILLE_PAR_ACTEL(villeService, id_actel);
                for(String lv:listeVille) {
                    comboBoxVille.addItem(lv);
                      }
          } catch (Exception e1) {
              System.out.println("Erreur SELECT ville");
        }  
    }

    protected void afficherLISTE_ACTEL_PAR_REGION() {
                 comboBox_ACTELS.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<String> (new String[] {"---------------------"}));
                 comboBoxVille.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<String>(new String[] {"---------------------"}));
                 List<String> listeActel= fonctionDAO.afficherLISTE_ACTEL_PAR_REGION(atlService, comboBox_gouver.getSelectedIndex()+49);
                  for(String la:listeActel) {
                      comboBox_ACTELS.addItem(la);
                      }
    }

    private void afficherLISTE_REGION() {
        List<Region> listeRegion= fonctionDAO.afficherLISTE_REGION(rgService);
          for(Region lr:listeRegion) {
                 comboBox_gouver.addItem(lr.getNom_region());
              }
    }

    private void JRadioButtonMenuItemTransfaire() {
    }

    private void JRadioButtonMenuItemNinstallation() {
    }


    private void JMenuDemandes() {
    }

    private void JMenuItemRegion() {

    }

    private void JMenuReseau() {
    }

     void action() { 
         new Thread(new Runnable() { 
             public void run() {
                 try {
                     progressBar.setValue(value);
                     value++;
                     Thread.sleep(15);
                     } 
                 catch (InterruptedException ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}

             if (progressBar.getPercentComplete() == 1.0) {
                 tr=true;
                 }

             else { tr=false;
                 action();}

             }
             }).start(); 

         }

     public int remplir_numero() {  
            String ville = comboBoxVille.getSelectedItem().toString();
            Listnumero.listModel.removeAllElements();
            PanelAffectationNumero.comboBox_choixN.removeAllItems();
            PanelAffectationNumero.comboBox_choixN.setEnabled(false);

            List<Numero> listeNum = fonctionDAO.afficherLISTE_NUMERO(numeroService, fonctionDAO.afficherID_VILLE_PAR_NOM_VILLE(villeService, ville));
            if(listeNum!=null){
            for(Numero ln:listeNum) {
                Listnumero.listModel.addElement(ln.getPlage_numero()+"");
              }
            return 1;
            }
            else{
            return 0;
            }
        }

       /* public int remplir_resedence(){
            PanelNouvelleInstallation.comboBoxResedence.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<String>(new String[] {"-----------"}));
            String nom_ville = comboBoxVille.getSelectedItem().toString();
            List<Ville> listeVille = fonctionDAO.afficherRESEDENCE_PAR_NOM_VILLE(villeService, nom_ville);
            if(listeVille!=null){
             for(Ville lv:listeVille) {
                 PanelNouvelleInstallation.comboBoxResedence.addItem(lv.getResedence());
              }   
             return 1;
            }
            else{
            return 0;
            }
        }*/

       /* public void remplir_voie(){
            int indextvoie= PanelNouvelleInstallation.comboBoxTypeVoie.getSelectedIndex();
            String type_voie =  PanelNouvelleInstallation.comboBoxTypeVoie.getSelectedItem().toString();
            String nom_ville = PanelRegionlACTEL.comboBoxVille.getSelectedItem().toString();

               if(indextvoie == 0){
                   PanelNouvelleInstallation.comboBoxVoie.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<String>(new String[] {"----------------"}));
                    }

               else{
                       PanelNouvelleInstallation.comboBoxVoie.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<String>(new String[] {"----------------"}));
                       List<Ville> listeVille = fonctionDAO.afficherVOIE_PAR_NOM_VILLE(villeService, nom_ville, type_voie);
                       if(listeVille!=null){
                               for(Ville lv: listeVille){
                                   PanelNouvelleInstallation.comboBoxVoie.addItem(lv.getVoie());
                               }
                       }
                   }
    }*/

        public int getcodePostal() {    
            String nom_actel = comboBox_ACTELS.getSelectedItem().toString();
            String nom_ville = comboBoxVille.getSelectedItem().toString();
            return fonctionDAO.afficherCODEP_PAR_NOM_VILLE(villeService, fonctionDAO.afficherNUM_ACTEL_PAR_NOM_ACTEL(atlService, nom_actel)+50, nom_ville);
        }

        public JButton getOkButton() {
            return okButton;
        }

        public void setOkButton(JButton okButton) {
            this.okButton = okButton;
        }

        public JButton getCancelButton() {
            return cancelButton;
        }

        public void setCancelButton(JButton cancelButton) {
            this.cancelButton = cancelButton;
        }

        public static Image scaleImage(Image source, int width, int height) {
            BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
            Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) img.getGraphics();
            g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
            g.drawImage(source, 0, 0, width, height, null);
            g.dispose();
            return img;
        }



        //avec une taille en pixels (=hauteur si portrait, largeur si paysage):
        public static Image scaleImage(Image source, int size) {
            int width = source.getWidth(null);
            int height = source.getHeight(null);
            double f = 0;
            if (width < height) {//portrait
                f = (double) height / (double) width;
                width = (int) (size / f);
                height = size;
            } else {//paysage
                f = (double) width / (double) height;
                width = size;
                height = (int) (size / f);
            }
            return scaleImage(source, width, height);
        }
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Seriously, why does it take almost 450 lines of code to show 'broken rendering in combo. box'?

Comment: setLayout(null) ... Well there your (first) problem

Comment: Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Combo Boxes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) for a working example.

Comment: but i'm using my jcombobox correctly

Comment: the problem is not with how to use Comboboxes

Comment: Hello, need some help pls.

Comment: hi, need some help pls.

Comment: If clicking on a JComboBox does not show its drop-down, you probably have an exception occurring on the AWT event dispatch thread.  Paste the entire stack trace of that exception (not a picture) into your question.

Comment: ok how to do that?

Comment: hello, more help pls.

Comment: Jcombobox not displayed correctly